# list inside list. how to access items inside of it

Tags: c#, list

I'm having some issues with my programm in c#.

Basically I have a list called `mainList` with 3 items in it. First two items are integers, but third one is another list containing more items.

```
mainList[0] = 8;
mainList[1] = 1;
mainList[2] = list;
```

By using foreach loop I'm able to print all of those items.

```
foreach (var i in (dynamic)(mainList[2]))
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

However I don't know how to access them. The thing is that I can't use indexes, because it is not an array. I would like to do something like this:

```
foreach (var i in (dynamic)(mainList[2]))
{
    // First item is in datetime type, so I would like to change it to int
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt64(i[1]));
}
```

Is there a way to access items inside list like we do it in arrays with a help of indexes?

Comment: Can you show the exact code of how you create all of your objects, and your `DateTime` instance

Comment: Why you have to put everything into the same collection even if it's not related with each other?

Comment: Create a model that has two `int` properties and a `List` property.

Comment: What is the type of `mainList`?

Comment: mainList is List<Object> type.

Comment: @CaL17: sure, but why you don't use classes?

Comment: Its only a fragment of my code, all of these functions are inside classes. I'm just showing small pieces of my code

Comment: @CaL17: no, i don't mean the class `Program` or `Form1`. I mean classes that describe your data model. With meaningful named properties with the correct types like `DateTime` or `List<int>`? Then you could put instances of these classes in a list, f.e. a `List<MyFirstUsefulClass>`

Comment: Can't you take your item out of your main list. check or it's a List by using .GetType and then locally cast it to a list using List localVar = (List) selecedItem and from then on use it like any List?

Comment: might consider a  `List<Tuple<int, int, List<T>>>` although it not looks nice, but this will allow avoid `dynamic` and `object` - there is no reason to use them in your code, and no new classes (if you prefer not to add new ones if possible)

Comment: @Vladimir: what the hell are you suggesting there? Why you want to avoid using real classes too? You want to work with these `Tuple<int, int, List<T>>` in the whole program? No one will ever understand that code.

Comment: I`m not like that as well ) but if @CaL 17 do not like to use new classes for some reason - there is a bad (agree that is not good) but solution in Tuples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists support the same index-based access as arrays, so you can use

```
mainList[n]
```

to access the nth entry in `mainList`.

Answer (score 0):

I `guess` you are looking for something like this, although it is really unclear what you're asking:

```
foreach(var item in mainList)
{
  if(item is System.Collections.IEnumerable)
  {
        foreach(var obj in ((System.Collections.IEnumerable)item))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(obj);
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: It just prints all of elements like my code above. My issue is that I cannot access them one by one. for example now it shows 5 items. I would like to select second one and print it.

Comment: That you can print them means you can access them right? in the second foreach loop add a if statement with the condition for the specific type of item you want to do stuff with and do it? or replace the second foreach loop with a statement only selecting the seccond item from a found list?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I want to do. How can I specify which item I want to print?

Comment: That depends, if the item you want to print is always on the same index you can use that. you replace the foreach loop with Console.WriteLine(((((System.Collections.IEnumerable)item)[index]; if you want to print a item that meets a specific requirement use an if statement in the foreach loop

Comment: By the way, in case that your list in the mainlist always has it's items in the same order. Why not make a class and put that in the main list? you can still use the if(item is MyClass) to find it and more easilly access it's content